# Unable to upload local files to google colab- file upload does not respond

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

I am new to google collab. I have imported a jupyter notebook from github but cannot upload files from my local machine. I have tried file upload button and the python code

```
from google.colab import files
uploaded = files.upload()
```

and neither of them respond. Did anyone have the same problem?

Comment: I'm also faced with the same error. I tried the below steps;
1. Tried to upload with the 'Upload' button on the left-hand side panel, under the files, but there was no response, willing to see Finder or Files explorer page. 
2. Imported google.colab library, and used import files function but again there was no response.

Answer (score 5):

Um, are you using Google Chrome with Google Collab? I'll give you a hint why it might not be working...Google. Trying using Google Chrome as your browser for Google Collab and I'll bet...ba bam...it suddenly works. Magic. F.A.N.G. wars.

Comment: Might be a bug? Or they intentionally do these kind of stuff? I tried with firefox with no luck, even tried to upload a very small file and nothing changed. But as soon as I installed chrome it worked perfectly fine even with an enormous file!

Comment: Exactly! Point proven.

Comment: Sounds weird but worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to upload files in colab.

1. Using Code:-

=> Copy This code from Below :

```
# import and Create new folder
import os
from google.colab import files
import shutil

new_folder = ‘New_Folder’

if os.path.isdir(new_folder):
  shutil.rmtree(new_folder)

os.mkdir(new_folder)

# Upload Files
uploaded = files.upload()
for filename in uploaded.keys():
  dst_path = os.path.join(new_folder, filename)
  print(f'move {filename} to {dst_path}')
  shutil.move(filename, dst_path)
```

2. Manually:-

=> Click  Show file browser(In Mobile Mode) or Click Folder Icon (In Desktop Mode)

[image: Screenshot 1] 
[image: Screenshot 2]

=> Open ‘content’ folder or other destination. Click 3 dot icon and you will find your options.

=> Now You can create new folder, delete folder, upload files, copy file path etc.

Note : Before trying above steps, Connect to your specific Runtime type.

Comment: Thank you for advising on how to code; for some reason, I cannot manualy upload no matter what I try. When I try to implement, I run into a problem on line 6 where I put in the directory and file but I get a FileNotFound Error

Answer (score 1):

I was on Firefox and manual uploads, but I was facing issues. It used to work mostly. I then tried using Google Chrome and it worked.

[Was getting a red circle with file upload status](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QED45.png)

Answer (score 0):

Simply put, you just need to press the button in the red circle and upload what you need.
[image]

Comment: Yes that is what I tried. The button does not respond..

Comment: 1. Close the tab and open a new one (don't refresh);
2. try another browser.

Comment: this does not work either.. @ Memphis Meng

Comment: Perhaps you can try uploading your files to Google drive first. And then allow your session to mount Google Drive.

Answer (score 0):

Open Google Colab
Mount your google drive and wait for it to happen.
Now upload your file at a suitable location on drive.

Go to colab.
Browse to your file location in google colab. Click on 3 dots at the right of the browsed file. click on copy path. use this path to open the file in code block of google colab.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).